# File being accessed by another process

Tags: c#

Disclaimer: Been through several similar threads with no success.

Hi Guys and Gals,
Working on a Twitch.tv chatbot and hit a problem with IOStreams.  I have a file (ViewerPoints.csv) that I'm storing some arbitrary points given for spending time in the channel that will be used for minigames I'm going to program in at a later date.  Now every instance of a StreamReader/StreamWriter is paired up with a .Close() before the next one would access it, however I am getting the following error:

```
System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024864
  Message=The process cannot access the file 'S:\Programming\Projects\C#\StarBot\StarBot\bin\Debug\ViewerPoints.csv' because it is being used by another process.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
       at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)
       at StarBot.Program.assignPoints() in S:\Programming\Projects\C#\StarBot\StarBot\Program.cs:line 156
       at StarBot.Program.Main(String[] args) in S:\Programming\Projects\C#\StarBot\StarBot\Program.cs:line 40
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Essentially the file is already in use but I can't figure out where it is being used and by what.  I've tried reboots (as I was opening and closing the program a lot), I've tried deleting a remaking the file.  From what I can see there are no other StreamReaders/Writers open when the exception is thrown but the Process Monitor is showing 2 instances of ViewerPoints.csv.

Full code is here all help much appreciated:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;

    namespace StarBot
    {
        class Program
        {
            private static DateTime time;
            private static double messageDelay = 30.0;
            private static DateTime nextMessage = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(messageDelay);
            private static string[] viewerArray;
            private static string ViewerPointsFile = "ViewerPoints.csv";
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //password from www.twitchapps.com/tmi
                //include "oauth:" portion
                IRCClient irc = new IRCClient("irc.twitch.tv", 6667, "Star__Bot", "oauth:likeidreallyleavethiskeyinhere");
                irc.joinRoom("dystarplays");
                getViewers();
                irc.sendChatMessage("Star__Bot Connected...");
                while (true)
                {
                    time = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    string message = irc.readMessage();
                    if(message!= null)
                    {
                        if (message.IndexOf('*') >= 0)
                        {
                            irc.sendChatMessage(processMessage(message));
                        }
                    }

                    if(time >= nextMessage)
                    {
                        assignPoints();
                        //print message from list
                        nextMessage = time.AddSeconds(messageDelay);

                    }
                }
            }

            private static void assignPoints()
            {
                getViewers();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ViewerPointsFile);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                string viewerPointsFile = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
                int points;
                string spoints;
                viewerPointsFile = viewerPointsFile.Replace("\r\n", ",");
                viewerPointsFile = viewerPointsFile.Remove(viewerPointsFile.Length - 1, 1);
                string[] viewerPoints = viewerPointsFile.Split(',');
                for (int i = 0; i< viewerPoints.Length; i= i + 2)
                {
                    string viewerInFile = viewerPoints[i];
                    bool added = false;
                    foreach (string viewerInChannel in viewerArray)
                    {
                        if (viewerInFile.ToLower() == viewerInChannel.ToLower())
                        {
                            spoints = viewerPoints[Array.IndexOf(viewerPoints, viewerInFile) + 1];
                            points = int.Parse(spoints);
                            sb.Append(viewerInChannel + "," + ++points + "\r\n");
                            added = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!added)
                    {
                        spoints = viewerPoints[Array.IndexOf(viewerPoints, viewerInFile) + 1];
                        points = int.Parse(spoints);
                        sb.Append(viewerInFile + "," + points + "\r\n");
                    }
                }
//error happens on the StreamWriter here
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ViewerPointsFile);
                spoints = sb.ToString();
                sw.Write(spoints);
                sw.Close();

            }

            private static string getPoints(string user)
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ViewerPointsFile);
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine().ToLower())!= null)
                {
                    if (line.IndexOf(user) >= 0)
                    {
                        return line.Replace(",",": ");
                    }
                }
                sr.Close();
                return user + ": 0";
            }

        }
    }
```

[EDIT] edited to remove unnecessary code.

Comment: that's an awful lot of code to be posting.. can you pinpoint exactly in the code where this is happening and update the question with that pertinent information we do not have time to read thru all of your code / code review especially if it's not working..

Comment: @MethodMan: Removed unnecessary code and added a comment to highlight the line where the error is thrown

Comment: @Dystar what value has `ViewerPointsFile` at the moment of the exception?

Comment: it has "ViewerPoints.csv" as defined at the top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would `Dispose` of your Stream objects that touch the file.

Or use `using` instead like:

```
using StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ViewerPointsFile)
    {
       spoints = sb.ToString();
       sw.Write(spoints);
    }
```

Quote from [MS link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**CLOSE** method: 
"Closes the current stream and releases any resources (such as sockets and file handles) associated with the current stream. Instead of calling this method, ensure that the stream is properly disposed"

Comment: Agree, but calling Close is the same.

Comment: better use `using`, as it will also dispose properly when an exception is thrown.

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia calling close does not guarantee the `Immediate Disposing` of the object.. Wrapping in a using is always best in this case

Comment: Agree, but in this case with code it is very unlikely that this is what is happening

Comment: @MethodMan: it is always better to check the code before talking. StreamReader.Close calls directly Dispose.

Comment: used `using` and it seems to have solved the issue, Looking at the resolution of the issue it looks like @MethodMan was correct about immediate disposal.

Comment: I'm pretty sure MS guidelines are to use Dispose, not simply Close to ensure the file handles are released. @IgnacioSolerGarcia...  I read it on their official site, will try to find the link